# Send enter from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, click, enter

***How to send enter from javascript to site?***

What I real need is to send text to site like filehippo.com in search box, and press enter to search for those text.
So piece of code from site is:

```
<div id="searchbox">
<form name="f" action="/search">
<input style="color: #999" type="text" id="q" name="q" maxlength="150" value="Search..." onfocus="javascript:clearInputValue('q', 'Search...')" onblur="javascript:setDefaultIfEmpty('q', 'Search...')">
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="GO" onclick="javascript:submitQuery('q', 'Search...')">
</form></div>
```

And my simple code look like this:

```
javascript: document.getElementById('q').focus();document.getElementById('q').value='Winrar';document.getElementById('f').item(0).click();
```

And those script just put focus on search box and send text to them, but I need also to do automatically search (send enter), how to do that?

```
document.getElementById('f').item(0).click(); -> dont work
```

What I need is to simulate click of mouse, by enter, cause can't send click to element that work properly.

Is it possible to send enter with text?

Comment: Why do you want to simulate click. Does the site use furthermore the bubbled click event, specifically  ? Why isn't document.getElementById('f').submit() good?

Comment: @ I don't know why getelementbyid dont submit as well, i try that on site and that don't work properly.

Comment: are there multiple items with the same id? ...maybe

Comment: @ as i can see from in that piece of code no

Comment: ah, of course, as @David Everlöf noticed, there is no id "f"..ad id to the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.f.submit();` to submit the form.

The problem is that there are multiple forms named 'f'

```
javascript:document.f[0].submit();
```

So the fully functional line would be:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('q').value='Winrar';document.f[0].submit();
```

Comment: i'm not sure this way of accessing an id is valid, at least not in all browsers. Submit is a function, i doubt this works

Comment: @StoiaAlex that want to submit i try it

Comment: @StoiaAlex How do you exactly put those line in firefox? I use google chrome and put in adressbox javascript:document.getelementbyid("f").submit(); and it don't search.

Comment: i'm sorry, I was mistaken, there is no "f" id, if you add id="f" to the form element it should work. But in this resolution the current answer to which we're commenting is valid, it should work.

Comment: @DavidEverlöf try it on this site http://www.filehippo.com/ when you put in search box something?

Comment: I dont get it to work there either.. Strange. It works in the jsfiddler example :/

Comment: @DavidEverlöf i don't have much experience in javascript, but thnx for  answer ... maybe will work on other sites ...

Comment: Updated answer because I found out why it wasnt able to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Use onkeypress attribute of input element.

Comment: this have to be automatically the script have to send key without iteration with user